# Get all towns and suburb information in GreaterLondon with their polygons

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have added below query in the `Overpass-API` to get GreaterLondon towns and suburb with polygons in the one query

```
[out:json][timeout:3000];
{{geocodeArea:london}}->.searchArea;
(
  relation[place="town"](area.searchArea);
  relation[place="suburb"](area.searchArea);
)
out geom;
```

But the results aren't good for me and I need each object to have information like below with geometry and other important info:

```
  [
    {
      "id": 196021, 
      geometry: [{"lat": 51.4139269, "lon": -0.1023109}]
      "lat": 51.6301762,
      "lon": -0.1748844,
      "tags": {
           "is_in": "Barnet, London, England, United Kingdom",
           "is_in:district": "Richmond upon Thames",
           "is_in:city": "Barnet",
           "is_in:county": "London",
           "name": "Whetstone",
           "place": "suburb",
           "wikidata": "Q150188",
           "wikipedia": "en:Whetstone, London"
       }
    },  
    {
      "id": 196022, 
      geometry: [{"lat": 51.4139269, "lon": -0.1023109}]
      "lat": 51.6301762,
      "lon": -0.1748844,
      "tags": {
           "is_in": "Barnet, London, England, United Kingdom",
           "is_in:district": "Barnet",
           "is_in:county": "London",
           "name": "Whetstone",
           "place": "town",
           "wikidata": "Q150189",
           "wikipedia": "en:Whetstone, London"
       }
    },
 ]
```

How can I improve my query to get the above results?

Comment: Whetstone is not a _relation_ but a _node_ in OSM: https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/196021  ... you need to change "relation" in your query to "nwr" to also include nodes and ways.

Comment: Yes, but how can I get a node data with their geometry? For example, I did this query for Greater-London to show me all town in it `[out:json][timeout:3600];
node(51.2867602,-0.5103751,51.6918741,0.3340155)[place=town];
out geom;` but I can't get geometry with them

Comment: Hmm, what exactly do you mean by "can't get geometry"? A node is simply a point, it only has a lat/lon, nothing else. Please use the "query" tool (question mark symbol) on osm.org to find out, if OSM has the data you're looking for. The only "polygon" like data are some boundary=adminsitrative relations, like https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/51831. Not sure if thiis is what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to say the response of overpass API with a `node` query cannot contain geometry and for geometry, as you mentioned I should use `boundary=adminsitrative`, but how can I find a relation between a node town and the geometry in the query? is there any way to get a town or suburb object with their geometry in it? if no what is the solution for that and can I find that?

Comment: Overpass API is just a mirror of the original OpenStreetMap database. If nobody has created a town or suburb as relation in OSM before, there's nothing you can do from Overpass API side, I'm afraid. Maybe try to get in touch with your local OSM community first.